# how to fix "no matching distribution found" when installing python packages on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pip, ubuntu-16.04

I have this error when i tried to install python packages.
When i run the command `pip install` it won't work and I have a message error that says

> no matching distribution found.

I tried to upgrade the pip version but still the same problem.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu gnome 16.04.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bzle.png)

Comment: Please avoid pics.

Answer (score 1):

There is no module [threading](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/threading) at PyPI (it's where from pip downloads packages). `threading` is a module from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), you don't need to install it.

Comment: gave me the same message error for the module operator

Comment: Because it's again a standard module. Please learn the standard library before downloading 3-rd party modules.